# Using search in react js

Tags: reactjs, search, filter

I want to filter content based on the input typed, I don't know where did I go wrong. Whenever I typed my input it just doesn't filter the content instead of that it is showing all the content there.

```
  function searchingFor(searchingTerm) {
        return function(x){
            console.log("searching",x);
            return x.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchingTerm.toLowerCase())|| searchingTerm;
        }
    }

    class Main extends React.Component{

        componentWillMount(){
            this.props.fetchTopicsTableContent(this.state.sortBy,'ASC',0,this.props.match.params.Occupation).then(result=> (this.setState({rows:result.payload.data})))
            this.props.countTableContent(this.props.match.params.Occupation).then(result=>(this.setState({count:result.payload})));
        }

        constructor(props){
            super(props);

            this.state={
                searchTerm:"",
                rows:""
            }
        }

    searchHandler(e){
            this.setState({searchTerm:e.target.value})
            // console.log("rows",this.state.rows)
            {this.state.rows.filter(searchingFor(this.state.searchTerm)).map(item=>{
                console.log(item);
                 // this.setState({rows:item})
            })}
        }

    render(){
        return(
            <form>
               <input type="text"
                  value={this.state.searchTerm}
                  onChange={this.searchHandler.bind(this)}
                />
            </form>);}}
```

Comment: why are you running `map`? and are you sure `searchingFor()` returns true results ?

Comment: just use parameter directly `filter(searchingFor(e.target.value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.setState({searchTerm:e.target.value})` #setState is async operation and if you want to complete action how this operations will finish.

You should use callback function as for the 2d argument: `this.setState({searchTerm:e.target.value}, () => {...here is your code})`

Comment: Yes you are correct, when I combine this and the comment which has been verified, this works. Thanks for the comment

Comment: When I try to use setState under this, error is showing up. Like I want the item there to store it in a state called rows. If you look up there you can see the comment inside the filter function. It is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript operator || is defined to return the left value if it evaluates to a truthy value, otherwise the right value instead of returning true itself. So try replacing this

```
return x.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchingTerm.toLowerCase())|| searchingTerm;
```

with

```
return x.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchingTerm.toLowerCase())|| false;
```

Answer (score 0):

your `searchingFor()` function is wrong. Make the provided changes:

```
this.state.rows
.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchingTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1)
.foreach(item => console.log(item));
```

You can use the spread operator to save the data